# bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard

Tags: matlab, glib

I am not sure how to solve this problem in CentOS7:

```
>> cluster_sample
MathWorks::System::IUserException [Error using matlab.internal.webwindow (line 310)
MATLABWindow application failed to launch. Unable to launch the MATLABWindow application

Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.platformhost.CEFFigurePlatformHost/createView (line 58)
                this.CEF = matlab.internal.webwindow(peerModelInfo.URL, peerModelInfo.DebugPort, position);

Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.FigureController/createView (line 223)
            this.PlatformHost.createView(this.PeerModelInfo, pos, title, visible, resizable, windowState);

Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebComponentController/add (line 75)
        obj.createView( parentController, parentView, map );

Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.WebCanvasContainerController/add (line 52)
            add@matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebContainerController( this, webComponent, parentController );

Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebControllerFactory/create (line 93)
                    component.createController( parentController, [] );]
MathWorks::System::IUserException [Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.services.core.eventhandling.WebEventHandlingService/setProperty (line 199)
       obj.ProxyView.PeerNode.setProperties( javaMap );

Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.WebCanvasContainerController/updateSceneChannel (line 137)
            obj.EventHandlingService.setProperty('SceneServer', propValue);

Error in matlab.ui.internal.controller.WebCanvasContainerController/set.Canvas (line 91)
            updateSceneChannel(obj);

Error in matlab.ui.internal.componentframework.WebControllerFactory/create (line 93)
                    component.createController( parentController, [] );]
>> simulink
Warning: MATLABWindow application failed to launch. Unable to launch the MATLABWindow application 
> In sltemplate.ui.StartPage/showWithFallback
  In sltemplate.ui.StartPage.show 

>> pwd

ans =

    '/scratch3/3d_pose/animalpose/leap'

>> cd(matlabroot)
>> pwd

ans =

    '/ifs/common/IT/matlab-9.4'

>> ! bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow
bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
>> ! bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow
bin/glnxa64/MATLABWindow: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard
>> 



(base) [jalal@goku animalpose]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
Release:    7.7.1908
Codename:   Core
(base) [jalal@goku animalpose]$ uname -a
Linux goku.bu.edu 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 13 23:58:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I solved it installing pango-devel package (seen in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563033/evince-symbol-lookup-error-usr-lib-libatk-1-0-so-0-undefined-symbol-g-log-s))

```
yum install pango-devel
```

I hope it helps!